# How can I search Dynamics CRM using OrganizationService for a specific record?

Tags: vb.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

If I know the accountId of a record I can do something like this:

```
 Dim cols As New ColumnSet(New String() {"name",
                                         "address1_postalcode",
                                         "lastusedincampaign"})
 Dim retrievedAccount As Account = _orgService.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols).ToEntity(Of Account)()
```

But what if I don't know the accountId and instead want to search for a record based on some other factor? Say, returning all records with "John" as the first name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the RetrieveMultiple method with a QueryExpression.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328300.aspx) for some examples

You could also use Linq to CRM, or Fetch XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use QueryExpression as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328300.aspx.

You can write your own ConditionExpression or FetchXml for the QueryExpression.

For more complicated query I like to use FetchXml. You can do Advanced Find then download the generated FetchXml, or use any number of online tools like Fetch Xml Builder to generate it first.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm... same exact url as mine, posted an hour later... anywho... Even though it is easy to generate the Fetch XML required, it is extremely difficult to maintain it or edit in code.  I would only use it in situations where you have to do some sort of counting or grouping, since Query Expressions and Linq to CRM don't support that...